# Allow cleveref to break between name and number

Tags: cross-referencing, line-breaking, cleveref

Assume that for external reasons [which are related to style but not to (La)TeX](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79467/linebreaking-inside-section-xxx) and not to be discussed here, I wish to allow `cleveref` to break a line inside "Section xxx"?  I.e., I am happy with

> ...[some long formula]... In Section
>
> 4.10.7 you will find the full proof.

The same goes for "Lemma xxx", "Definition xxx", and all similar situations. How do I allow `cleveref` to introduce line breaks?

Comment: FWIW, give `\crefformat{section}{Section #2#1#3}` a try. I don't recommend it, for sure.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not aware of a global setting of this kind.

Comment: @Mico: Sadly this is true, but it should have such features.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Do you want to contact Toby Cubitt and suggest he provide a global option of this type? He's very approachable; e.g., several years ago, I approached him about making it easy to have `\cref`-generated cross-references look like those generated by `\autoref`, and within a couple of weeks he issued an update with the new global option `nameinlink`. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I'll keep it in mind...

Answer (score 4):

The package `crossreftools` (current version is 0.6 which is available on CTAN) provides two macros named `\crthypercref` and `\crthyperCref` that basically act like `\cref` and `\Cref` (with `nameinlink` option) and allow for breaking of cross - references and displaying like `cleveref` would do, but only for a standard format, i.e. it does not take some `\crefformat` settings into account (This is on my TODO - list for the package, however!)

If no hyperlinks are desired, use `\crtcref` and `\crtCref` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}% nameinlink is not really necessary
\usepackage{crossreftools}


\begin{document}
% Just for testing:
\parindent=0em
\section{A very long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long , long, long, long, long, long, long section title} \label{foosection}

Using \verb!\crthypercref!

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line: \crthypercref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\crthyperCref!

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line: \crthyperCref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\crtcref!

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line: \crtcref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\crtCref!

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line: \crtCref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\cref!

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line: \cref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\Cref!

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line: \Cref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\cref! again with extra letters on the line

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line (ext): \cref{foosection} we see... 

Using \verb!\Cref! again with extra letters on the line

Now some dummy text in order to force breaking at the end of the line (ext): \Cref{foosection} we see... 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice package! Good to know it exists!

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks.... Some bloke from Black Forest spent some time and wrote a package that does not another package, just using kernel macros ;-)

Comment: I did not even have to look at the author name, the colourful layout of the documentation was enough of a give-away :)

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, and no Ducks were harmed by writing it ;-)